# Css nav submenu mobile don't work

Tags: html, css, navigation, submenu

I'm building a nav menu with sub-menus with just CSS (media queries too) and html.

It works fine visualy, but the problem is:
On the mobile browser, When I click in any sub-menu, it won't work, sometimes it just redirect to the first menu address and sometimes it don't even redirect. On the computer browser it works fine too.

Here is my code:

```
#nav{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

#nav ul{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}


#nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: black solid 2px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
}

#nav ul li:hover{
    background: #47350e;
}

#nav ul li a{
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 15px;
}

#nav ul li a:hover{

}

#nav ul li .children li{
    border: 0px;
}

#nav ul li .children li a{
    font-size: 13px;
    top: 5px;
    font-weight: normal;
}


#nav ul li .children li a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#nav ul li .children{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 46px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #47350e;
    padding-left: 120px;
    z-index: 5;
}

#nav ul li:hover .children{
    display: block;
}
```

and HTML

```
<div id="nav">
            <ul id="nav-items">

                <li>
                    <a href=#>option 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href=#>option 2</a>
                    <ul class="children">
                        <li>
                            <a href=#>option 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href=#>option 4</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: I suppose the problem is `:hover` pseudoclass. On mobile (touch) devices you can't really "hover" an element. You need to detect such devices and use some JS to show submenu on click.

Answer (score 3):

For mobile Version u can use Select menu.

```
   <div id="mobile_menu">
    <select>
<option>option1</option>
<option>option2</option>
<option>option3</option>
</select>
    </div>
```

CSS is
In normal css

```
#mobile_menu{display:none;}
```

For mobile

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px) {
    #mobile_menu{display:block;}
#nav{display:none;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really want to use that.
My client is a bit anoying :)
And he want the style the designer did.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your `#nav ul li a {` rule is creating the mess.

```
position: relative;
top: 15px;
```

is working for both the levels, i.e. option 1 and option 3

Check if this is the issue. If do not resolve please share the link to your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I didn't get that.
Ok, maybe it's messing up, but what can I do?

here is the link:
http://ighormartins.sytes.net/Dropbox/OpticaDaFabrica/